# The usage of "to be" in double comparatives?

Tags: comparatives

I read when "be" is used in double comparative, it is **sometimes** omitted in the book of "Top Notch", like:

> The better the quality of health care (is), the higher the life expectancy (is).

According to the above rule, do I have to eliminate both "is" or could I remain either of them?
What if I keep both of them?

Comment: It is usual to omit both.

Comment: It's usual to omit both (rather than just one _or neither_), as I think @Kate says. I think the fuller version tends to be  'The better the quality of health care is, the higher the life expectancy will be.' There's an implied conditional in the first quantifying. But the double deletion is still the norm. _The more, the merrier_.